# NDSolve for closed-loop system with Unit Delay (attempt to compare with Simulink)

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, nonlinear

I'm trying to reproduce a scheme from Simulink with a unit delay.

[image]

To do this, I use the NDSolve command with an additional equation that implements a unit delay loop.

The results do not match, and I associate this with a misunderstanding of how the unit delay and the joint solution of the algebraic and differential equations using the NDSolve command.

Help fix the error.

[image]

[image]

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
pars = {α = 1, Subscript[W, origin] = 1, η = 1, u = 1}
s = NDSolve[{x'[t] == -α*x[t] + Tanh[x[t]]*Subscript[W, o][t] +
      u, Subscript[W, o][t] == 
    Subscript[W, origin] + 
     Subscript[W, o][t - 0.001] + η*Tanh[x[t]], x[0] == 0, 
   Subscript[W, o][t /; t <= 0] == 0}, {x, Subscript[W, o][t]}, {t, 0,
    10}]
Plot[Evaluate[{x[t] /. s}], {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
Plot[Evaluate[{Subscript[W, o][t] /. s}], {t, 0, 10}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: How did you determine that the results do not match?  They look very similar.  Ideally, you would plot the difference of the two results.